# Example of submanifold without subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I am interested in giving an example for a closed, connected submanifold of a connected manifold which does *not* carry the subspace (or relative) topology.

With some help from *Boothby* (III.4 p.71-72), I believe an example could be the following:

Let $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by

$$F(t) = \left( 2 \cos\left( t - \frac{1}{2} \pi \right), \sin 2 \left(t - \frac{1}{2} \pi \right) \right) {;}$$

the image is a figure eight. Now, let $g(t)$ be a monotone increasing smooth function on $- \infty < t < \infty$ such that $g(0) = \pi$, $\lim\limits_{t \to - \infty} g(t) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} g(t) = 2 \pi$ (e.g., we may use $g(t) = \pi + 2 \arctan{t}$). Then define $G : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by composition of $g(t)$ with $F(t)$:

$$G(t) = F(g(t)) = \left( 2 \cos \left( g(t) - \frac{\pi}{2} \right), \sin 2 \left( g(t) - \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \right) {;}$$

note that $G(t)$ is an injective immersion. By definition, it follows that $G(\mathbb{R}) = \tilde{N}$ is a submanifold (or immersed submanifold) of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

From this point, it gets tricky and I am unsure of how to show whether or not $\tilde{N}$ is closed. *Boothby* notes that $\mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic (under $G$) to $\tilde{N}$ considered as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. It seems reasonable that $\tilde{N}$ is closed, if $\mathbb{R}^2 - \tilde{N}$ is open, though I would like to be able to justify this rigorously.

Is this an example of what I am looking for? If not, could someone point me in the right direction? Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected, and thus $\tilde{N}$ is connected.

Comment: I seem to recall Spivak's differential geometry volume 1 mentioning this example (not with explicit formulas, but still) quite early on and say that this is the only thing that can go wrong when embedding a manifold as a submanifold of another manifold. I don't remember the exact quote, so I can't recall exactly what "this" refers to, though, or the exact hypotheses. If I could, this would've been an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I found what you were referencing in Spivak Vol.1 (p.48): "If $M_1 \subset M$ is an immersed submanifold, and $f : P \to M$ is a $C^\infty$ function with $f(P) \subset M_1$, it is not necessarily true that $f$ is $C^\infty$ when considered as a map into $M_1$, with its $C^\infty$ structure." He then proceeds to provide this example (without an expression), mentioning $f$ is not continuous, in this case, as a map into $M_1$.

Comment: Right, I remember now. So it wasn't exactly what you were after. The "this" I was referring to was that discontinuity of $f$ was the only thing that could go wrong. If $f$ is $C^0$ as a map into $M_1$, then it's $C^\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more direct injective immersion that gives a figure 8 is the map $(-\pi/2,3\pi/2) \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $t \mapsto (\sin 2t, \cos t$). It's an immersion because the derivative never vanishes. By definition, the image of this map is an immersed submanifold. Moreover, the image is closed as a subset of the plane. One way to see this is to note that this image is exactly the locus of points $(x,y)$ such that $x^2 = 4y^2 (1-y^2)$. Therefore, it is the fiber of $0$ under the continuous mapping $(x,y) \mapsto 4y^2 (1-y^2) - x^2$, whence it is closed.

[This is Example 7.2 in Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds".]

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that reference. If I wanted to show that the image does not carry the subspace topology? Do I exhibit an open set in the image that is not of the form $U \cap \tilde{N}$ (where $\tilde{N}$ is the image under this map and $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$)?

Comment: @Ph.K. The topology given to the image of an injective immersion $F:N \to M$ is defined by $U \subset F(N)$ open iff $F^{-1}(U) \subset N$ open, and the coordinate charts are compositions of coordinate charts for $N$ composed with $F^{-1}$. This makes $F:N \to F(N)$ into a diffeomorphism. In this case, this means that the figure 8 with the immersed submanifold topology is diffeomorphic to the open interval $(-\pi/2,3\pi/2)$. In particular it isn't compact, so it cannot carry the subspace topology. (The image with the subspace topology is closed and bounded, hence compact.)